# Django - python-social-auth: Facebook returns anonymous user

Tags: python, django, facebook, python-social-auth

I'm using python-social-auth on my Django website to connect with social accounts. I've managed to work with with Twitter and Google, but I'm having problems with Facebook. On the URI callback, `request.user` gives me 'AnonymousUser'. These are my settings:

**settings.py:**

```
...
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth',
    'social.backends.twitter.TwitterOAuth',
    'social.backends.yahoo.YahooOpenId',
    'social.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = 'xxx'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = 'xxx'

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'users.pipeline.require_email',
    'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details'
)

AUTH_EXTRA_ARGUMENTS = {'redirect_uri': PROJECT_DOMAIN + '/auth/'}

...
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
url(r'^auth/$', views.auth_complete),
...
```

**views.py**

```
...
def auth_complete(request):
    return HttpResponse(request.user) # this gives me AnonymousUser
...
```

Please warn me if I omitted any setting.

Answer (score 0):

Your pipeline should looks like this:

```
   SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
        'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
        'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
        'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
        'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
        'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
        'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
        'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
        'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
        'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
        'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
        'accounts.social_auth_pipeline.get_profile_data', # custom
        'accounts.social_auth_pipeline.get_profile_avatar', # custom
    )
```

[here on git issues](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/39) more details

Comment: That did not work for me also that last two lines I think they are not necessary. However, i am also using `graphql_auth` and `graphql_social_auth` at the same time could an interfering cause such a problem? @mexekanez

Comment: You should also check `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` it could be duplicated or it may have mistakes, or missing from your settings.

Comment: also, the order inside of  SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE has sense follow documentation as it is. Thanks